# In ASP.NET Core how do you check if request is local?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

In the regular ASP.NET you could do this in a view to determine if the current request was from localhost:

`HttpContext.Current.Request.IsLocal`

But I can't find something similar in ASP.NET 6/Core/whatever it is meant to be called.

Comment: Be careful with the usage of `HttpContext.Connection.IsLocal`. It seems to me that the usage of `HttpContext.Connection.RemoteIpAddress` is **more safe way**. If I connect to test ASP.NET 5 RC1 project locally I see `::1` in `RemoteIpAddress`, but `HttpContext.Connection.IsLocal` is `false`. It's wrong.

Comment: Cheers Oleg, what you said turned out to be true for me too.

Comment: I get the same behaviour too. It's always ```false``` locally.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

**UPDATE: ASP.NET Core 2.0 has a method called `Url.IsLocalUrl`** (see this [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/preventing-open-redirects?view=aspnetcore-2.1#islocalurl)).

I *think* this code will work, but I haven't been able to test it completely

```
var callingUrl = Request.Headers["Referer"].ToString();
var isLocal = Url.IsLocalUrl(callingUrl);
```

But see Will Dean's comment below about this approach:

> Anyone thinking about using the 'updated' version which checks the Referrer header should bear in mind that headers are extremely easy to spoof, to a degree that doesn't apply to loopback IP addresses.

---

**Original solution**

I came across this looking for a solution to knowing if a request is local. Unfortunately ASP.NET version 1.1.0 does not have a `IsLocal` method on a connection. I found one solution on a web site called [Strathweb](http://www.strathweb.com/2016/04/request-islocal-in-asp-net-core/) but that is out of date too.

I have created my own `IsLocal` extension, and it seems to work, but I can't say I have tested it in all circumstances, but you are welcome to try it.

```
public static class IsLocalExtension
{
    private const string NullIpAddress = "::1";

    public static bool IsLocal(this HttpRequest req)
    {
        var connection = req.HttpContext.Connection;
        if (connection.RemoteIpAddress.IsSet())
        {
            //We have a remote address set up
            return connection.LocalIpAddress.IsSet() 
                  //Is local is same as remote, then we are local
                ? connection.RemoteIpAddress.Equals(connection.LocalIpAddress) 
                  //else we are remote if the remote IP address is not a loopback address
                : IPAddress.IsLoopback(connection.RemoteIpAddress);
        }

        return true;
    }

    private static bool IsSet(this IPAddress address)
    {
        return address != null && address.ToString() != NullIpAddress;
    }
}
```

You call it in a controller action from using the `Request` property, i.e.

```
 public IActionResult YourAction()
 {
     var isLocal = Request.IsLocal();
     //... your code here
 }
```

I hope that helps someone.

Comment: This helped me. [Here](https://gist.github.com/firelizzard18/74e7481fb97c16b90bfd801798f53319) is my version.

Comment: Anyone thinking about using the 'updated' version which checks the Referrer header should bear in mind that headers are extremely easy to spoof, to a degree that doesn't apply to loopback IP addresses.

Comment: The `Referer` request header has nothing to do with whether the remote IP is from local or not.

Answer (score 22):

At the time of writing `HttpContext.Connection.IsLocal` is now missing from .NET Core.

Other working solution checks only for a first loopback address (`::1` or `127.0.0.1`) which might not be adequate.

I find the solution below useful:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using System.Net;

namespace ApiHelpers.Filters
{
    public static class HttpContextFilters
    {
        public static bool IsLocalRequest(HttpContext context)
        {
            if (context.Connection.RemoteIpAddress.Equals(context.Connection.LocalIpAddress))
            {
                return true;
            }
            if (IPAddress.IsLoopback(context.Connection.RemoteIpAddress))
            {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

And the example use case:

```
app.UseWhen(HttpContextFilters.IsLocalRequest, configuration => configuration.UseElmPage());
```

Comment: This method can be simplified to `public static bool IsLocalRequest(HttpContext context) => context.Connection.RemoteIpAddress.Equals(context.Connection.LocalIpAddress) || IPAddress.IsLoopback(context.Connection.RemoteIpAddress);`.

Comment: Shouldn't the 2nd `if` read `if (IPAddress.IsLoopback(context.Connection.LocalIpAddress))` instead of using `RemoteIpAdress`?

Comment: I don't think it makes a difference in practice, function can return false if someone crafts a connection to the external interface address from loopback or the other way around but that's not what happens by default so any IP address from 127 range or IPv6 will be picked up regardless of if it's a remote check or local. Also, since the check is about a remote connection to the server, checking remote address fits the purpose better.

Comment: Can this be spoofed?

Answer (score 5):

None of the above worked for me.

[Url.IsLocalUrl](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.iurlhelper.islocalurl?view=aspnetcore-2.2) works very different and I find it a bit useless:

For example, the following URLs are considered local:

```
  /Views/Default/Index.html
  ~/Index.html
```

The following URLs are non-local:

```
  ../Index.html
  http://www.contoso.com/
  http://localhost/Index.html
```

`HttpContext.Connection.IsLocal` doesn't exist in .Net Core 2.2

Comparing `ControllerContext.HttpContext.Connection.RemoteIpAddress` and `ControllerContext.HttpContext.Connection.LocalIpAddress` also doesn't work in my test because I get "::1" for remote ip and "127.0.0.1" for local ip.

Finally, I used this piece:

```
IPAddress addr = System.Net.IPAddress.Parse( HttpContext.Connection.RemoteIpAddress.ToString() );
if (System.Net.IPAddress.IsLoopback(addr) )
{
    //do something
}
```

Answer (score 4):

### UPDATE for ASP.NET Core 3.1

You can use this:

```
if (Request.Host.Host == "localhost") {// do something }
```

Answer (score 3):

Late to the party, but if I want to check IsLocal in razor views in .Net core 2.2+, I just do this:

```
@if (Context.Request.Host.Value.StartsWith("localhost"))
{
    //do local stuff
}
```

Comment: This is a very ugly way to do it. What if you have a site called localhost.site.com? Or even localhosting.com.

Answer (score 2):

I would also mention that it may be useful to add the below clause to the end of your custom `IsLocal()` check

```c#
if (connection.RemoteIpAddress == null && connection.LocalIpAddress == null)
{
    return true;
}
```

This would account for the scenario where the site is being ran using the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.TestHost` and the site is being ran entirely locally in memory without an actual TCP/IP connection.

Comment: This seems like a reliable mechanism to infer running as a WAF (or similar) test, without relying on deployment environment or (potentially spoofed) Local vs. Remote IP detection.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

now its

```
HttpContext.Connection.IsLocal
```

and if you need to check that outside of a controller then you take a dependency on `IHttpContextAccessor` to get access to it.

Update based on comment:

`HttpContext` is intrinsically available in Views

```
@if (Context.Connection.IsLocal)
{

}
```

Comment: I take the dependency in the view by doing this `@inject IHttpContextAccessor Context;` right? Currently is local is always false...

Comment: This is going away in RC2. Filip has an alternative approach here: http://www.strathweb.com/2016/04/request-islocal-in-asp-net-core/ but even it seems to depend heavily on other middleware and which server you're using.

Answer (score 0):

While not strictly answering the question, if the use case is to distinguish between a local development environment and a hosted environment, you could just use `IWebHostEnvironment`'s `IsDevelopment()` method. Of course, this doesn't work if you are trying to find out whether a hosted site is accessed directly from the host machine.