# Custom Authorize filter with aspnet core

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

Hi I am trying to create a custom authorize filter that will allow me to authorize requests coming from localhost automatically (which will be used for my tests).

I found the following one for Asp.net however am having trouble porting it to asp.net core.

```
public class MyAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        if (httpContext.Request.Url.IsLoopback)
        {
            // It was a local request => authorize the guy
            return true;
        }

        return base.AuthorizeCore(httpContext);
    }
}
```

How can I port this to asp.net core?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can create a middleware in which you can authorize requests coming from localhost automatically.

```
public class MyAuthorize
{
   private readonly RequestDelegate _next;
   public MyAuthorize(RequestDelegate next)
   {
      _next = next;
   }

   public async Task Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
   {
     // authorize request source here.

    await _next(httpContext);
   }
}
```

Then create an extension method

```
public static class CustomMiddleware
{
        public static IApplicationBuilder UseMyAuthorize(this IApplicationBuilder builder)
        {
            return builder.UseMiddleware<MyAuthorize>();
        }
}
```

and finally add it in startup `Configure` method.

```
app.UseMyAuthorize();
```

Asp.Net Core did not have `IsLoopback` property. Here is a work around for this
https://stackoverflow.com/a/41242493/2337983

You can also read more about [Middleware](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware) here

Comment: The problem with doing authentication/authorization with middleware is that it can't honor the [AllowAnonymous] attribute.