# Redirect to specific URL if cookie exists

Tags: c#, cookies, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm currently trying to go to specific URL if the cookie exist.

For example

```
/ANYCONTROLLER/ANYMETHOD to /CONTROLLER2/METHOD2
```

Currently my Authentication cookie is configured like this :

```
 app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
 {
     AuthenticationScheme = "AmcClientCookie",
     AutomaticAuthenticate = true,
     AutomaticChallenge = true,
     LoginPath = new Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.PathString("/Public/Home"),
     CookieSecure = hostingEnvironment.IsDevelopment()
                  ? CookieSecurePolicy.SameAsRequest
                  : CookieSecurePolicy.Always,
     ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(1)
 });
```

I tried to do it in a custom **authorization handler** but I do not have access to **HttpContext**.

So I tried to do it in a **Action Filter** but it seems that I do not have access to the **Authentication** to know or not if the user is connected.

If somebody have an idea.

Comment: This may help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41293420/custom-authorize-filter-with-aspnet-core

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There may be other ways, but Middleware seems the most appropriate to this ([more info](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware)).

**The short method**:

On your `startup.cs` class, in `Configure` method, **after** `app.UseMvc(...)` call, add the following:

```
app.Use((context, next) =>
{
    if (context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        var route = context.GetRouteData();
        if (route.Values["controller"].ToString() == "ANYCONTROLLER" &&
            route.Values["action"].ToString() == "ANYMETHOD")
        {
            context.Response.Redirect("/CONTROLLER2/METHOD2");
        }
    }

    return next();
});
```

**The long method**:

Create a class named **UrlRewriteMiddleware.cs** with the following:

```
public class UrlRewriteMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;
    public UrlRewriteMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        _next = next;
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {

        if (context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            var route = context.GetRouteData();
            if (route.Values["controller"].ToString() == "ANYCONTROLLER" &&
                route.Values["action"].ToString() == "ANYMETHOD")
            {
                context.Response.Redirect("/CONTROLLER2/METHOD2");
            }
        }

        await _next.Invoke(context);
    }
}
```

Create another class named MiddlewareExtensions.cs with the following:

```
public static class MiddlewareExtensions
{
    public static IApplicationBuilder UseUrlRewriteMiddleware(this IApplicationBuilder builder)
    {
        return builder.UseMiddleware<UrlRewriteMiddleware>();
    }
}
```

On your `startup.cs` class, in `Configure` method, **after** `app.UseMvc(...)` call, add the following:

```
app.UseUrlRewriteMiddleware();
```

You can also use

```
context.Request.Path = "/CONTROLLER2/METHOD2";
```

instead of redirect, but the browser Url will not reflect the new path and will show the first path. If it is supposed to show an error or denied message, then perhaps **Path** is more appropriate.

I'm assuming that you're using the asp.net authentication channel, so you can test authentication as in the example. If not, you can access cookies in

> context.Request.Cookies

**Quick note (read comments)**

`GetRouteData` returns null before Mvc routing is setup. So, you must register this middleware after Mvc routing setup.

If for any reason you must do it earlier, you may access the url through `request.Request.Path` and parse it manually.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your answer this look to be what I need. Just a issue with the long method, **context.GetRouteData()** retrieve null.

Comment: You are right... **GetRouteData** returns null while MVC routes aren't setup. I believe that in this case you can register it after **app.UseMvc** call, as I see no drawback on it. Or you can use **context.Request.Path** to access the Url and parse it manually. I'll update the answer to reflect it.

Comment: Thanks, Is what i'm currently using to do my redirection.