# Show DeveloperExceptionPage in production but for 'Remote Only"

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor-pages

I understand that the debug error page should not be seen by the end user.

However in the past, I have always been able to configure my production deployment to hide this information (so show a custom or generic error page) when called remotely, but still show the exception/stacktrace debug error, as long as I called it direct from the webserver it was hosted on.

Now looking at the latest MVC/RazorPages way, is it the case this is no longer possible, and it is either on or off, depending on the environment variable?

Before:

Within Web.Config, I use to be able to do something like:

```
<system.web>
<customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" </customErrors>
```

Now:

In Startup.cs:

I can see

```
if (env.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
}
else
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
}
```

... but I cannot see a way to allow "app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();" when env.isDevelopement == false, but the call is local.

I am hoping I am missing something, rather than something that has now been removed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it to work (all thanks to others on here).  Hopefully it might help others to see the bits I needed, in one place.

First to address identifying if the call is local:

As for:

```
Url.IsLocalUrl
```

Supposedly it works, but is 'spoofable'.  Given that it could reveal source-code/debug, the guys on this page ([In ASP.NET Core how do you check if request is local?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35240586/in-asp-net-core-how-do-you-check-if-request-is-local)) suggest something more like:

```
public static class HttpContextFilters
{
    public static bool IsLocalRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        if (context.Connection.RemoteIpAddress.Equals(context.Connection.LocalIpAddress))
        {
            return true;
        }
        if (IPAddress.IsLoopback(context.Connection.RemoteIpAddress))
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public static bool IsRemoteRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        return !IsLocalRequest(context);
    }
}
```

I can now call in Statup.cs:

```
if (env.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
}
else
{
    app.UseWhen(HttpContextFilters.IsLocalRequest, configuration => configuration.UseDeveloperExceptionPage());
    app.UseWhen(HttpContextFilters.IsRemoteRequest, configuration => configuration.UseExceptionHandler("/Error"));
}
```

For an alternative solution, I suspect @Jon Galloway's approach would yield a more elegant and expandable solution...

Something along the lines of:

```
  public class MyDeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware : Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

    public MyDeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware(RequestDelegate next, 
        IOptions<DeveloperExceptionPageOptions> options, 
        ILoggerFactory loggerFactory, 
        IHostingEnvironment hostingEnvironment, 
        DiagnosticSource diagnosticSource) : base(next, options, loggerFactory, hostingEnvironment, diagnosticSource)
    {
        _next = next;
    }

    public async new Task Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
    {
        if (HttpContextFilters.IsLocalRequest(httpContext))
        {
            //Show dev exceptions page
            await base.Invoke(httpContext);
            return;
        }

        await _next(httpContext);
        return;
    }

 public static class MyDeveloperExceptionPageMiddlewareExtensions
    {
        public static IApplicationBuilder UseMyDeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware(this IApplicationBuilder builder)
        {
            return builder.UseMiddleware<MyDeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware>();
        }
    }
```

Then in StartUp.cs do:

```
app.UseMyDeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware();
```

For some reason though (due to my ineptness), I couldn't quite get VS to like debugging it, but appeared to work when run from a web server.  However, for what I need, and also given the fact that it would need finishing off to handle the custom error page, I think the simplified down and dirty approach above, is enough for me.

Answer (score 2):

You could possible extend [DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/master/src/Middleware/Diagnostics/src/DeveloperExceptionPage/DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.cs#L90), or create your own copy, using Url.IsLocalUrl to only display the error view on localhost.