# ASP.NET Core - Identify if Request is Local

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have an ASP.NET Core 3.1 app. In this app, I have some views that are using Razor. In this view, I want to be able to do something like this:

```
@if (Request.IsLocal)
{
  // do this
}
else
{
  // do this
}
```

Unfortunately, [HttpRequest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.httprequest?view=aspnetcore-5.0) class doesn't have a direct way to identify if a URL is local. My question is, how do I identify in my Razor view is a Request is local?

Comment: The only was is to get the remote endpoint and compare IP of machine.

Comment: Does this solution work for you - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35240586/in-asp-net-core-how-do-you-check-if-request-is-local

Comment: @alexv Thank you for your response. The challenge is, the `Url` class doesn't seem available in the Razor view. Which would imply I need to import it. However, because it's an abstract class, I can't seem to figure out how to get a `Url` instance from the `Request` in the Razor view. I see `Url.IsLocalUrl(callingUrl);` however, I don't know what namespace the `Url` class lives in, so I can't seem to figure out what I need to import.